# creating RecurrentPaymentsProfile on ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal

I saw several question on this subject here but all are without answers.
So i hope somebody will help me.
How to provide subscription through NVP API?
For example i sell accounts for $10 per month. 
So i provide ExpressCheckout for 1 month and get $10 for it. And then i create subscribtion on this account for every month but with startdate from next (after already payed by ExpressCheckout one month) month?

Answer (score 0):

You would call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and set the PROFILESTARTDATE to one month ahead in the future. This would subsequently start billing after one month.
See also https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_CreateRecurringPayments
as well as 
https://www.x.com/node/2760